# Select parent and count of children in Nhibernate using Linq in the same query

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am trying to learn MVC and nHibernate by creating a simple blog application.

I have a posts table and a comments table. Each post can have multiple comments. Now in my view I have to display the details of the post and the number of comments.

I tried the below code

```
(from post in DbContext.Posts
where post.ScheduledDate <= DateTime.Now && post.Approved == true
orderby post.ScheduledDate descending
select new { Post = post, CommentCount = post.Comments.Count() }).Take(10);
```

This returns the below SQL:

```
SELECT top 10 count(comments1_.Id) as y0_ 
FROM Posts this_ 
left outer join Comments comments1_ 
         on this_.Id=comments1_.PostId 
WHERE (this_.ScheduledDate <= '2009-12-29' and this_.Approved = 1) 
ORDER BY this_.ScheduledDate desc
```

And obviously throws a sql exception that `group by` is not used.

Comment: Which version of the NHibernate Linq provider are you using?  The latest version in the trunk or the NHContrib separate DLL one?

Comment: I am using the one that uses the criteria api. The NHContrib one.. Is it safe to use the one in the trunk? Like is there enough documentation for a newbie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was some weird issue with the NHContrib LINQ provider. I upgrade to version 3 of nHibernate and the new LINQ provider seems to be working perfectly well for the same query.

Answer (score 0):

That generated sql does look wired, i've translaated it into lambda style.
Try it. If you don't have [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)  go grab it and check it out will ease up your life alot.

```
  DbContext.Posts
    .Where(p=>p.ScheduledDate<=DateTime.Now && p.Approved)
    .OrderByDescending(p=>p.ScheduledDate)
    .Select(p=> new{ post= p,CommentCount = p.Comments.Count()})
    .Take(10);
```